# What is the purpose of a Normal vector to any plane, why do we find it at all?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, machine-learning, plane-geometry

I am asking this question as I'm not aware why there is a need of 'Normal Vector' in case of a plane/hyper-plane. Please could someone help me understand what would happen in the absence/presence of a normal vector to the plane. If possible, explain as if you are explaining it to a 5 year old kid with real life examples so it helps me to relate things!

Many Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: The normal vector describes the way the plane faces. If you shone a light along the normal vector to the plane it would bounce straight back at you. Knowing this vector, you can calculate the intensity of the light scattered back at you if you don't point it along the normal vector too. That's one use.

Comment: @Paul so you mean to say a Normal Vector of a plane describes how its placed/positioned in the n-dimensional space ? is that it a Normal used for ?

Comment: If you know the normal vector (which way it faces) and a point the plane goes through (where it is) you know the plane.